# How to split layer in After Effects using marker of markers and javascript, extendscript?

Tags: javascript, split, marker, extendscript, after-effects

I am trying to split layer in After Effects using extendscript. First of all, i want get the time value of the marker. Then i want set the Timeline cursor on necessary point on the Timeline. And finally i'll split layer to pieces.

How did this in javascript? Maby you know how get time parameter from marker and then use this value to shift  Timeline cursor from necessary  position?

Or you know other way how do it?

Comment: I found this: alert(myLayer.property("Marker").keyTime(indes of markers))

Comment: A google search with the term "split layer at marker" gives me at least these two scripts that do exactly what you are asking for. http://aescripts.com/pt_layermarkers/ http://www.motion-graphics-exchange.com/after-effects/Split-At-Markers/4c44af203df8b You can take a look into the second one how they did it (the first one is closed source).

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to duplicate the layer:

```
var newLayer = myLayer.duplicate();
```

Then set the inPoint of that layer to the marker time:

```
newLayer.inPoint = myLayer.property("Marker").keyTime(<index of marker>)
```

And the outPoint of the original layer:

```
myLayer.outPoint = myLayer.property("Marker").keyTime(<index of marker>);
```

Then if you need to set the comp time to the marker time just use the time property of the comp object (I'm assuming here that there's a variable called `myComp` which is set to the comp object, eg `var myComp = app.project.activeItem`):

```
myComp.time = myLayer.property("Marker").keyTime(<index of marker>);
```

Before you spend too much more time trying to nut this out, it's worth reading the [After Effects Scripting Docs](https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/), and if you want GUI fun also read the [Extendscript docs](https://extendscript.docsforadobe.dev/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of markers for spliiting the layer.Just you have to duplicate the layers and make the use of intime and outtime and set them accordingily.For the splitting of between layer the original will be splitted to the required three layers or portions. So I have given the :

```
var portions =3;
```

You can make the use of inPoints and outPoints to mark the interval for the layer for splitting :

```
var sliceTime = 15.0; //give the end time for the part of layer)
var origOutPoint = layer.outPoint;
comp.time = sliceTime;
while (portions > 1) {
    var d = layer.outPoint - sliceTime;
    dupeLayer = layer.duplicate();
    layer.outPoint = dupeLayer.inPoint = sliceTime;

    sliceTime = 20.0;
    portions--;
    layer = dupeLayer;
}
```

Hope this might help you.